# How to setup autoNumeric to accept a 0 as first number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using `autoNumeric` plugin with the latest version of `jQuery`.

I have a mobile number textbox and I need it to be able to accept a 0 as the first number.  How would I do this?  I currently have the following:

```
$('.phone').autoNumeric({ vMin: '0', vMax: '99999999999999999999' });
```

..but when I type in a 0 and then another digit then the 0 is oberwritten by this digit.  Mobile numbers here can start with a 0, for example: 0987656512.  I just need autoNumber to prevent anything else from being typed in except numbers.  How would I do this?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use some other plugin. Mobile numbers aren't integers, they have to be handled as strings.

Comment: I agree with Juhana, as international numbers can be valid in the following format `+44 (0)203 xxx xxxx`, without the `x`s of course.

Comment: That [autoNumeric plugin](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) is awesome, it can also round your phone number to two decimals!

Comment: We don't have phone numbers with decimals :)  How do you get it to work on mobile numbers starting with a 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the `jQuery masked input plugin`.  I handles numeric only values well.  It allows me to enter a value like 0123.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider autoNumeric's recently released `lZero` which focuses on the permissions for leading zeros.

> **lZero: "deny"** - allows only one leading zero (same behavior as versions 1.7.0 to 1.7.4.
>
> **lZero: "allow"** - allows leading zeros to be entered. Removes leading zeros on the focusout event.
>
> **lZero: "keep"** - allows leading zeros to be entered. Keeps leading zeros on the focusout event.

Reference: http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Comment: **NOTE**: If you use "keep" and go beyond the max length of numbers, your leading zero(s) will be removed, that's something autoNumeric needs to work on.